# How to define a bijective (one to one) relation in alloy

Tags: alloy

I have three signatures in alloy as bellow:

```
sig A{}
sig B{}
sig C{}
```

How can I define a bijective relation (or isomorphism) between C and A+B.

Comment: Bijections are both one-to-one and onto/injective and surjective. I am not familiar with alloy to assist you further, but I thought I would make sure the definition of bijection was clear. Furthermore, as I am unsure if you were using the terms synonymously, an isomorphism is not just any bijective map. It must be a bijective linear map (it must preserve the addition and scalar multiplication of the vector space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bijection relation need to be injective and surjective. so the answer would be as following:

```
sig A {}
sig B{}
sig C{r : one A+B}

fact { 
    all c1,c2: C | c1.r=c2.r implies c1=c2   // r is injective
    all ab: A+B | some c:C | c.r=ab   // r in surjective
}
```

Probably there is shorter way to write this. The other people might comment.

Thanks

Comment: [code]fact r_bijective{r in C one->one (A+B)}[/code] ought to be enough.